# Is it possible to access part of a file during loading in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv

Say I have a 10mb CSV file I want to load into a JavaScript app using AJAX (or other). Is it possible to read from it during the loading?

So if 50% of it was loaded, is it possible to access that first 50% of the file?

Comment: can you get the server to paginate the data?

Comment: Have you considered chunking up the data?

Comment: the eyes cannot read 10mb of data instantly, pagination is your friend

Comment: Im actually not trying to load a huge file, Im actually just wondering if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should be possible, since the file is read one row at a time, you just need to make a function that will loop through the rows already read and display the information.

Comment: Any idea how you would do it? Can you get access through a normal request during a progress event?

Comment: I don't think so. The AJAX readystate won't be set to 4 until the file has been received completely. There's no readystate for a partial response.

Comment: I think this would be the best solution, [Import CSV contents with PHP](http://www.ehow.com/how_5154452_read-csv-file-php.html), tell me if this works for you. And it should actually work with AJAX, i just don't think it's a good idea to hit the server every second and print out what the loop read so far from the file, coming back to what i said earlier. You can look up the function on php.net for more info. [fgetcsv Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)